# Node Streams: Wait until data is available

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I have 3 streams (A,B,C) which are piped into another (A->B->C).
When I start my program B's _read get's called immediatly because it's piped to C. However there is no data in the B-stream yet as A fetches data async. Once B receives the data, which is passed to the _write method of B, it transform the data and emits an 'readable' event (which I fire manually - is this the supposed way of doing it?).

However nothing happens and the data from B is not consumed by anyone (hence B's _read is not called). I can workaround this by calling (on B) this._read() at the end of my _write() method. But this could potentially also push data to the consumers although the queue is full, right?

Basically I want to send a larger chunk of data into the B-stream, split it into smaller ones, and then pass those on to C one by one. So I want to have some kind of buffer in B.

```
_read(size) {
    if(this._lineBuffer.length > 0) {
        var stop = false;
        while(!stop) {
            stop = this.push(this._lineBuffer.splice(0,1));
        }
    }
    if(this._pendingWriteAck) {
        this._pendingWriteAck();
        this._pendingWriteAck = null;
    }
}

_write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log("New chunk for line splitter received");
    if(this._buffer) {
        this._buffer = Buffer.concat([this._buffer, chunk]);
    } else {
        this._buffer = chunk;
    }
    for (; this._offset < this._buffer.length; this._offset++) {
        if (this._buffer[this._offset] === 0x0a) { // 0x0a is a new line
            this._lineBuffer.push(this._buffer.slice(0, this._offset).toString());
            this._buffer = this._buffer.slice(this._offset + 1);
            this._offset = 0;
        }
    }

    if(this._lineBuffer.length > this._maxLineBuffer || this._buffer.length > this._maxRawBuffer) {
        console.log("Line Split buffer has reached capacity. Waiting...");
        this._pendingWriteAck = callback;
    } else {
        callback();
    }

    setImmediate(()=>{
        this.emit('readable');
        this._read();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Transform stream for the "B" stream:

```
const Transform = require('stream').Transform;

const B = new Transform({
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this._offset = this._offset || 0;
    this._buffer = this._buffer ? Buffer.concat([this._buffer, chunk]) : chunk
    for (; this._offset < this._buffer.length; this._offset++) {
      if (this._buffer[this._offset] === 0x0a) { // 0x0a is a new line
        if (this._offset) {
          this.push(this._buffer.slice(0, this._offset), encoding);
        }
        this._buffer = this._buffer.slice(this._offset + 1);
        this._offset = 0;
      }
    }
    callback()
  },
  flush(callback) {
    if (this._buffer && this._buffer.length) {
      this.push(this._buffer);
    }
    callback();
  }
});
```

You can see it working by doing something like:

```
let line = 0
B.on('data', (chunk) => process.stdout.write(`${++line}. ${chunk}\n`))
B.write(['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Qux', 'Hello '].join('\n'))
B.write(['World', 'The End'].join('\n'))
B.end()
```

The output to your terminal will be:

```
1. Foo
2. Bar
3. Baz
4. Qux
5. Hello World
6. The End
```

Comment: But unlike a readable stream i cannot detect if 'C' or the queue between B and C is actually full, right? In my case the Producer, A, ist faster then 'C' and I want to use B to also backpressure to A.